# XNA 4.0. Значение не может быть неопределенны

Tags: c#, xna

System.ArgumentNullException: "Значение не может быть неопределенным."
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Насчет color1, 2 и т.д
https://pastebin.com/kd58iU35

Comment: значит, вы не задали значение переменной `color1`.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, к сожалению нет, задал.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код метода, где инициализируется переменная `color1`.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko https://pastebin.com/RfPJZQ23

Comment: А как `selected` задается? Откуда берется значение для этого идентификатора?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko https://i.imgur.com/tD2Mz3A.png

Answer (score 0):

У вас параметр `gameOverFont` инициализирован неправильно (фактически, у вас `gameOverFont = null`). Вероятно, вы передаете неправильный параметр в метод `Content.Load<SpriteFont>`.

В метод `Content.Load<SpriteFont>` вы должны передать `assetName` вашего шрифта. Для того, чтобы узнать/изменить данное свойство, выделите нужный шрифт и в окне `Обозреватель свойств` найдите свойство `Name` (если я не ошибаюсь). Его значение и нужно передавать в данный метод

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/xV5qJT4.png
https://i.imgur.com/k2uMcei.png

Comment: @Dubzer изменил ответ, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: assetName в content.load у меня указан правильно.

Comment: @Dubzer тогда последнее, что я могу посоветовать, сделать точку останова и посмотреть, какие значения у переменных. Уверен, что или `color1` или `gameOverFont` равны null